# optimize a small loop of if-else branch in c++

Tags: c++, optimization, iterator

Is it possible to remove the branches in the following loop. All iterators are from the container type `std::map<type_name, T>`

```
  record_iterator beginIter = lastLookup_;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  record_iterator endIter = lastLookup_;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  ++endIter;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  for(;endIter != end(); ++beginIter, ++endIter){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    time_type now = beginIter->first;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    if(ts == now){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      lastLookup_ = beginIter;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      return beginIter;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }else if(ts > now && ts <= endIter->first){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      lastLookup_ = beginIter;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      return endIter;
    }
  }
```

The problem that this algo is trying to solve is to optimize the forward lookup which location is assumed to be the same or (not too far ) forward of the last looked up location. Ideally, I kept an iterator of last looked up location, and move forward linearly. But this seems to have the same performance as,

```
  record_iterator it= sliceMap_.find(ts);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  if(it !=end()){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    return it;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  }else{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    return sliceMap_.upper_bound(ts);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  }
```

I feel that the problem is the branch, so it is possible to remove the branch in this code so I can profile the different in speed?

Comment: where does ts come from?

Comment: @John probably the argument to the function, saying where he's looking

Comment: Unless your map is huge and your result is very close to `beginIter`, I think the latter will be faster because it doesn't have the overhead of transverse a RB-Tree in-order.

Comment: @Yakk I asked for that I guess :)

Comment: I was going to say something similar to Murilo - you are traversing the nodes of the tree as opposed to a find which will skip nodes and find the correct point (log n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three big problems with the first approach:

- Too many comparisons inside a loop.
- Using iterators on a `std::map` involves using `std::map<>::iterator::operator++()`, which is not exactly fast. Look at the implementation starting at line 62: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/tree_8cc-source.html .
- Using iterators on a `std::map` is a linear search. Searching on a map should be logarithmic.

There's also a problem with your second approach. You are searching twice.

Why don't you just use

```
return sliceMap_.lower_bound(ts);
```

This should do exactly what you want with one logarithmic search.

Answer (score 2):

As some people said, the first method doesn't make a lot of sense since you are doing a linear search on an ordered container. I realize the location is supposed to be near *lastLookup*

About the second method, I think a simple optimization would be eliminating the second lookup. You are doing one on **record_iterator it= sliceMap_.find(ts);** and another one on **return sliceMap_.upper_bound(ts);**

EDITED:
Try out doing it this way:

```
record_iterator it = sliceMap_.lower_bound(ts);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
return it;
```

What we are doing there is, using lower_bound() to find the first element whose key doesn't compare less than ts (that includes an equal element which upper_bound() doesn't do).

Comment: You do not want to add 1 (`it++`) here. The function `lower_bound` is perhaps misnamed. The name suggests that the return value is the last element that is less than or equal to the provided key. That's not how it works. `lower_bound` instead returns the first element that is not less than the provided key. For example, if the keys in the map are 1.0 and 2.0 lower_bound(1.5) will return the iterator that points to the value with key=2.0, not 1.0.

Comment: @DavidHammen you're right, I edited it accordingly, thank you!

Comment: I changed my downvote into an upvote based on your edit. I used to get confused by `lower_bound` until I realize that it's just misnamed. It should be named `map::least_upper_bound`.